# Is there a way to type punctuation using pynput?

Tags: python, pynput

Whenever I type punctuation in the string such as a "?" it always gets transformed into "a".

I tried looking up specific keycodes but there was nothing shown for that.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time
keyboard = Controller()
data = list(input("type in the thing you want to say"))


def keystroke():
    for temp in data:
        if temp.islower():
            keyboard.press(temp)
            keyboard.release(temp)
            time.sleep(0.03)
        else:
            with keyboard.pressed(Key.shift):
                keyboard.press(temp.lower())
                keyboard.release(temp.lower())


keystroke()
```

Right now I can type a string with upper letters with is cool but I just want to know a way to return punctuations.
If I type in "Hello!"
it will return "Helloa"

Comment: There is an open issue on GitHub about this problem: https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/140

Comment: The latest version (V1.4) have some problem, you can use (V1.3) which don't have this problem.